# MySQL query to get id ranges in chunks

Tags: mysql

I have a table `items` with an auto-incrementing column `id` which is not contiguous (ie some items have been deleted).

Assuming I want to get item ids in chunks of 1000, such that I have a list like:

```
| min     | max     |
|---------|---------|
| 1       | 999     |
| 2500    | 1000000 |
| 2000000 | 2300000 |
```

would it be more efficient to run multiple queries e.g

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM item WHERE id > n LIMIT 1000) item_alias
```

where `n` is the previous max (starting with 0), or is there an sql query I can write to perform this in MySQL?